# Why aren't my click() to on() conversions working as expected?

Tags: jquery

The .click in jquery is deprecated. So I made amendments to the existing code, however, there seems to be some issue.

```
    GetPageButtons() {
    let $saveButton = $("<input />", {
        type: "button",
        value: "Save",
        class: "button large save",
      }),
      $cancelButton = $("<input />", {
        type: "button",
        value: "Cancel",
        class: "button large cancel",
      });
    $saveButton.click(() => {
      this.UpdateRecord();
    });
    $cancelButton.click(() => {
      this.modal.success = true;
      let _parent = this;
      $.each(_parent.fields, function (i, field) {
        delete this.newValue;
        this.element.val("");
      });
    });
    return [$cancelButton, $saveButton];
  }
```

The above code works, although my linter complains saying it deprecated.

```
  GetPageButtons() {
    let $saveButton = $("<input />", {
        type: "button",
        value: "Save",
        class: "button large save",
      }),
      $cancelButton = $("<input />", {
        type: "button",
        value: "Cancel",
        class: "button large cancel",
      });
    $saveButton.on("click", function() {
      this.UpdateRecord();
    });
    $cancelButton.on("click", function() {
      this.modal.success = true;
      let _parent = this;
      $.each(_parent.fields, function (i, field) {
        delete this.newValue;
        $( this ).element.val("");
      });
    });
    return [$cancelButton, $saveButton];
  }
```

The refactor to the suggested use of .on('click', fn){} however is not functioning. I get an error that says:

"Uncaught TypeError: this.UpdateRecord is not a function".

Why? It should work the same as the .click which is shorthand for .on.
Any suggestions???

Comment: Can't see anything in [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/) that says `.click()` is deprecated

Comment: Your issue is that you've switched from arrow functions to regular ones

Comment: @Phil the warning comes up in VSCODE. However, the .on should still work.

Comment: @dangerprone my mistake, `click()` is deprecated but the [docs are out of date](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/972)

Comment: @Phil also you are right about the arrow function. I neglected to consider lexical scoping. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work, because you are using normal function in contrast to the original code that used arrow function.

This means that the `this` inside the functions refers to something different.

Change it to

```js
$saveButton.on("click", () => {
  this.UpdateRecord();
});
$cancelButton.on("click", () => {
  this.modal.success = true;
  let _parent = this;
  $.each(_parent.fields, function(i, field) {
    delete this.newValue;
    $(this).element.val("");
  });
});
```

and it should work as originally.